# Android GridView focus order

Tags: android, gridview, focus

Help me, please! How can I set an order to changing focus in gridview with edittexts?
Now it looks like this:

(1)(2)(3)

(4)(5)(6)

(7)(8)(9)

When I press "Next" on keyboard, focus move 1-4-7 finish 2-5-8 finish 3-6-9. I need 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9... items adding dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an instance of your `EditText` in the code, then call `edittext1.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.edittext2);` and hence do this for all youre `EditText`.